# Почему в разных браузерах сайты на одном и том же разрешении отображаются по-разному?

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, responsive, масштабирование

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему при использовании инструментов по отображению сайта в разных разрешениях, разные браузеры выдают сайт по разному при одном и том же разрешении?

Chrome, как я понял просто масштабирует. То есть мой сайт выглядит таким же и на разрешениях выше.
[image: Отображение в Хроме]

Mozilla же идёт более сложным путём.
[image: Отображение в Mozilla]

То есть я установил одинаковую ширину экрана в пикселях, но браузеры мне выдают страницу по-разному. В таком случае разработчику приходится создавать медиазапросы отдельно для разных движков браузеров. То есть, по сути. двойную работу выполнять, что, разумеется, не хочется и не нужно.

В общем у меня 2 вопроса к профессионалам:

1. Как мне сделать так, чтобы страница во всех браузерах по одинаковой логике изменяла отображение при изменении разрешения?
2. Почему меня обманывают (и обманывают ли?) эти встроенные инструменты браузеров?

Comment: 566 != 535. Это разные разрешения.

Comment: @PavelMayorov предположу, имеется в виду лишь ширина. Вёрстку, которая зависит от высоты, делают редко

Comment: Мета width=device-width прописана? Если нет, то возможно хром отмасштабировал под 1024 пикселя, надо прописать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно установить

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

в head.
Скорее всего дело именно в этом.

А не вособенностях движков браузеров.
Если хотите узнать можно ли использовать то или иное css свойство, то следует пользоваться https://caniuse.com/

Comment: О да! Помогло. Буду изучать что это за чудный тег

Answer (score 10):

Давным-давно, в далёком-далёком прошлом десятилетии, когда мобильники были ещё слишком слабые и ничего толком не умели, все веб-сайты (не считая WAP, который отдельная история) делали только для компьютеров. Соответственно, вёрстка была адаптирована под соответствующую ширину экрана в районе тысячи пикселей. Когда начали появляться первые попытки запихнуть что-то полноценное в телефон, браузерам ничего не оставалось делать, кроме как прикручивать масштабирование. Ведь сайтов под мобильники никто тогда ещё не делал (кроме отдельных WAP), а если пытаться упихнуть вёрстку, сделанную под ширину 1024 пикселя, в ширину 128 пикселей (типичная ширина экранов мобильников того времени), то всё разъедется.

Вот так и жили с Opera Mini 4:

[image] [image]

Apple решила не мириться с этим, и, чтобы появилась возможность делать сайты не только под компьютеры, но и под <s>мобильники</s> революционный айфон™, для мобильного Safari придумала специальный meta-тег viewport, который управляет этим масштабированием и позволяет его отключить. <sup><sub>(точной даты его изобретения найти не удалось)</sub></sup> Со временем он стал де-факто стандартом и нынче поддерживается подавляющим большинством мобильных браузеров.

Ради совместимости со старыми сайтами поведение при отсутствующем meta viewport осталось прежним: они масштабируются под примерно 1024 пикселя по ширине (инструменты в моём Chrome отмасштабировали под 980 пикселей).

[image]

([код тестовой страницы](https://jsfiddle.net/ymmpbt5d/))

Инструменты Firefox масштабирование не делают. Почему — не знаю. Может, не посчитали это нужным. Но вот хром по личному опыту показывает картинку очень близкую к той, которая будет на реальных айфонах и айпадах, со всеми масштабированиями, и ему в целом можно верить (разве что высота скачет из-за разного размера адресной строки, но это мелочи). Скриншот с реального айфона (клик для увеличения):

[image]

Так как чаще всего современные веб-сайты делают адаптивными и автоматическое масштабирование им не нужно, можно его отключить с помощью вышеупомянутого мета-тега viewport. Чаще всего он имеет примерно такой вид:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
```

Это пихается в head. В данном виде он устанавливает ширину, равную ширине экрана (в CSS-пикселях, но про CSS-пиксели отдельная история) и таким образом отключает масштабирование:

[image]

[image]

Мета-тег viewport имеет много разных опций, подробнее о которых можно почитать [на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) или [прямо у Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html).

Answer (score 0):

Отображение разное в разных браузерах потому что они спецификации HTML, CSS и JS реализуют по разному, + версии этих спецификаций, + версии браузеров. Эта проблема давно известна, и с этим ничего не поделаешь.

Варианты решения:

1. Костыли в коде.
2. Использование фреймворков или библиотек.

   (которые внутри себя содержат *Костыли в коде*)