# Сохранение высоты меню при повороте (Вертикально -> Горизонтально)

Tags: html, css

Допустим, есть меню:

```css
.top{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #d32013;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
</div>
```

При отображении на телефоне - у меня не сохраняется пропорция высоты при наклоне. Что мне делать? Тестирую на iPhone и iPad

Comment: Если вам нужны размеры, пропорциональные ширине экрана, используйте единицу измерения `vw` — `100vw` это ширина экрана

Comment: нет, размер должен быть фиксирован. Чтобы при повороте высота блока не изменялась

Comment: В вашем коде она и так строго 200 пикселей

Comment: @andreymal но на iPhone она изменяет значение при наклоне... сейчас проверю еще раз код

Comment: Возможно, вы забыли прописать meta viewport и ваши айфоны-айпады масштабируют страницу так, чтобы имитировать ширину 980 пикселей https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/733042

Comment: @andreymal да, как раз это и забыл прописать) Спасибо за помощь