# Настройка области просмотра на телефоне

Tags: html, мобильная-разработка

Здравствуйте!

Уже долгое время не могу найти способ реализации. Все что нашел не работает в полном объеме.

Есть сайт: http://b-sales.kz/rbbrands/about_us.html
Задача: Сделать так, чтобы на телефоне сайт открывался в полном размере (ширина 1200)

Пробовал через вивпорт, и пока лучше это вивпорт на ширину 1200, но все равно на телефонах открывает сильно приближенно

Верстку смотрю в этом сервисе: http://deviceponsive.com/?url=b-sales.kz%2Frbbrands

Кто знает как сделать?

Comment: Забыли прописать тег [meta viewport](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/733042)

Comment: Не забыл. Вот же https://pp.userapi.com/c830400/v830400727/5aacc/Qu2UIyySMLQ.jpg  Или не там где-то?